# Cannot Connect to Jira Server in Rest Client

Tags: java, eclipse, jira-rest-api

I am currently using the following method to connect to the JIRA server and get data. This works perfectly fine but when I call this method in a Dynamic Web Project it does not execute and I am not able to make the connection to the server, Eclipse throws new exception everytime. I am getting ClassNotFoundException error classes already present in my libraries.

```
 URI jiraserverURI = new URI("https://jira.xxxxx.com");
     JiraRestClientFactory restClientfactory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
     JiraRestClient Client = restClientfactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraserverURI, username,
            password);
```

Stacktrace is following:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [GetProjectList] in context with path [/webappExample] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
    at GetProjectList.getProjectListFromServer(GetProjectList.java:43)
    at GetProjectList.doGet(GetProjectList.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to know what is wrong with this approach. Is there any configuration or buildpath issues ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
<artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.17</version>
<scope>provided</scope> <!-- Uses the application's SAL instead of bundling it into the plugin. -->
</dependency>
```

From

https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/shared-access-layer/adding-sal-dependency

Comment: I added the jar file externally but it still shows the same exception. Any particular reason ? @breakline  Also it gives this 

Description Resource Path Location Type
Classpath entry /Users/kandarp.gandhi/Downloads/sal-api-2.11.6.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.

Comment: Are you sure its on the classpath? Can you import it in any Java class?

Answer (score -1):

The solution was rather a simple one. I added all the jars to the deployment path and it did the work for me .